# How would I go about removing the entirety of this cabinet as cleanly and safely as possible?

Tags: cabinets, removal

I’m looking to remove the whole thing from the corner of the two walls including the trim. Links to tutorials or lists of tools would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!

[image]

Comment: Is there a false back? might be hiding something...

Comment: Any chance of posting pictures of the inside so we can see how it's built and attached to the walls and so forth?

Comment: Do you know if the sheet rock continues all the way to the (now hidden) corner?

Comment: Note that there may not be wallboard behind this, so you may not be able to "remove" it without putting up new wallboard, mudding, and painting. And the angle may be in how the building is framed  rather than because the cabinet is there. How important is it to you that this cabinet be removed?

Comment: VTC: This cannot be answered with the limited information provided.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest

1. Check inside to ensure that there isn't another reason for it to be angled
2. Remove the doors by unscrewing the hinges
3. Remove the frame for the door
4. Remove the drywall from the front
5. Remove the trim at the front
6. Finally tackle the sides.

Tools - hammer and pinch-bar should be enough.  You may need a hacksaw or a reciprocal saw to cut any hard to remove nails.